# EROR: control reaches end of non-void function [-Werror=return-type] error in C++

Tags: c++, stack

I need help to solve this problem. I am getting an error which is given below and code is also given. This program is to find whether **bracket is balanced or not**.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include<stack>
using namespace std;

// Complete the isBalanced function below.
string isBalanced(string s) {
    stack <char> st;
    for(auto c:s){
        switch (c){
            case '(':
            case '{':
            case '[':
                  st.push(c);
                   break;
            case '}':
                if(st.empty() || st.top()!='{' )
                    return "NO";
                st.pop();
                break;
            case ']':
                if(st.empty() || st.top()!='[')
                    return "NO";
                st.pop();
                break;
            case ')':
                if(st.empty() || st.top()!='(')
                    return "NO";
                st.pop();
                break;
            default: break;
        }
    }

}

int main()
{
    ofstream fout(getenv("OUTPUT_PATH"));
    
    int t;
    cin >> t;
    cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    
    for (int t_itr = 0; t_itr < t; t_itr++) {
        string s;
        getline(cin, s);
        
        string result = isBalanced(s);
        
        fout << result << "\n";
    }
    
    fout.close();
    
return 0;
}




this is a program to check bracket is balanced or not.
```

this is the code I have written and it's throwing me the error. Please help me to fix this problem.
I have tried by adding stack header file but still, I am getting same error.

```
***Solution.cpp: In function ‘std::__cxx11::string isBalanced(std::__cxx11::string)’:
 Solution.cpp:7:18: error: control reaches end of non-void function [-Werror=return-type]
    stack <char> st;
              ^~
 cc1plus: some warnings being treated as errors***
```

Comment: At the end of the function, just put `throw "How did we get here";` and it should compile without a warning.

Comment: first  [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) second [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095/6345323) therd what is the return param of your function?

Comment: Read your function carefully. What _would_ happen if your routine got an empty string as an input? What _should_ happen in such case?

Comment: @Eljay Please be nice to beginners. ;)

Answer (score 0):

No `return` statement will executed in your `isBalanced` function when the `for` loop is completed without executing `return` statement inside that.

It seems you should add code to check if the stack `st` is empty and return proper things according to its result after the loop.